# MacOS Sierra - cmake failed with qt5

Tags: c++, macos, qt, cmake, qt5

I'm trying to build a cpp/qt5 project using cmake, but the compilation return an error regarding QT5.

I've installed QT5 with Homebrew,

When I do :

```
brew --prefix qt5
```

I get

```
 /usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.6.0
```

---

So I'm in the `build` folder of my project, and I do :

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=$(brew --prefix qt5) -G Xcode -DBUILD_TESTS=ON -DBUILD_TESTS_COVERAGE=off
```

Return me this error :

```
    CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:124 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindQt5.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5" with any of
  the following names:

    Qt5Config.cmake
    qt5-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "Qt5_DIR"
  to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Qt5" provides a
  separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
```

the lines of errors in the CMakelist.txt :

```
    ## QT5 ##

find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Gui Widgets Concurrent Qml Quick REQUIRED)

set_target_properties(${BIN_NAME} PROPERTIES AUTOMOC ON)
set_target_properties(${BIN_NAME} PROPERTIES AUTOUIC ON)
target_link_libraries(${BIN_NAME} PUBLIC Qt5::Core PUBLIC Qt5::Widgets PUBLIC Qt5::Gui PUBLIC Qt5::Qml PUBLIC Qt5::Quick PUBLIC Qt5::Concurrent)

#########
```

---

I've also tried to add a `-DQt5_DIR=$(brew --prefix qt5)` to the command, same result.

---

Any ideas ?
thanks

Comment: Does file `Qt5Config.cmake` exists in your QT5 installation?

Comment: How do I verify that ?

Comment: I am not familiar with brew, but it definitely should be able to provide list of files for installed packages. But in given case it is sufficient to search given file under `/usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.6.0`: variable `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` just adds new *prefixes* for search things. As for variable `Qt5_DIR`, for having an effect this directory should directly contain required file.

Answer (score 22):

Try:

```
-DQt5_DIR=$(brew --prefix qt5)/lib/cmake/Qt5
```

Note that you can specify multiple properties when using `set_target_properties`, and specify `PUBLIC` scope for multiple values when using `target_link_libraries`:

```
set_target_properties(${BIN_NAME}
    PROPERTIES
    AUTOMOC ON
    AUTOUIC ON
)
target_link_libraries(${BIN_NAME}
    PUBLIC
    Qt5::Core
    Qt5::Widgets
    Qt5::Gui
    Qt5::Qml
    Qt5::Quick
    Qt5::Concurrent
)
```

Comment: Note: `qt5` in homebrew has been deprecated, but you can use `qt` instead, `$(brew --prefix qt)`, and `brew install qt@5.11` for example.

Comment: You can still use qt5 lately I built Miktex on Mojave using qt5, when something is deprecated it does not mean it won't work